# Latest Zustand data cannot be accessed when the callback functions of registrations are hit

Tags: reactjs, callback, registration, zustand

We have included a few registrations on the component mount.

```
const [valA, valB] = useStore();
 
useEffect(() => {
  serviceA.registerUpdate(handleUpdate);
  return () => {
    serviceA.unregisterUpdate(handleUpdate);
  }
},[])

const handleUpdate = () => {
  //Do some logic with valA and valB
  //The component re-rendered with latest valA and valB but still
  //valA and valB are always initial values that are available during mount.
}
```

Every time when valA or valB changes, I m getting a re-render to the component which is the expected behavior of Zustand.

But when the service triggers an update and when handleUpdate() is called, the latest data from the store is not available. I can only access the data that is set in store during mounting of the component.

```
const [valA, valB] = useStore();
 
useEffect(() => {
  serviceA.registerUpdate(handleUpdate);
  return () => {
    serviceA.unregisterUpdate(handleUpdate);
  }
},[valA, valB])

const handleUpdate = () => {
  //Do some logic with valA and valB
  //Able to access updated valA and valB.
}
```

The latest data can be accessed only if I have a useRef inside my component that will be set every time the valA is updated. Another way is to **have the registrations on useEffect of valA and valB** instead of mount. But I must have these registrations only on mount.

Is there any way I can get the latest Zustand data when the handleUpdate callback is triggered?

Comment: Do you only want to run serviceA.registerUpdate() only once during mount with latest values instead of initial values set by Zustand?  If so, then do you think it's happening because the value update takes some time before which the useEffect is firing on mount?  Can you please confirm these points?

Comment: Yes, I want serviceA.registerUpdate() to be registered only on the mount (on load of the application). After the component is mounted, the Zustand store is updated by other components/methods. I m getting a re-render on my component mentioned above but as it is just a render, mounted registrations won't happen again.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand. So I think the issue is, useEffect is using the initial value, because it’s firing before the values are being updated by some outside code. What is the values of valA and valB during initialisation? Null? Undefined? Empty array? Empty object?

Comment: The initial value is empty object

Answer (score 0):

I will make the assumption that this is a timing issue. The problem is being caused by useEffect executing on mount when Zustand
simply hasn't finished processing and updating the state of valA and valB. As a result handleUpdate function is still using the
initial values of state while being triggered
So we need to add some condition to make sure that the useEffect only fires registerUpdate() after the state update and only fire
once. If my assumption is correct than this approach should work

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [valA, valB] = useStore()
    const [isRegistered, setIsRegistered] = useState(false)
  
    const isEmptyObject = obj => Reflect.ownKeys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!isEmptyObject(valA) && !isEmptyObject(valB) && !isRegistered) {
        serviceA.registerUpdate(handleUpdate)
        setIsRegistered(true) // conditionally need to be set to true when registerUpdate() didn't throw an error. 
      }
      
      return () => {
        serviceA.unregisterUpdate(handleUpdate)
      }
    }, [valA, valB, isRegistered])
  
    const handleUpdate = () => {
      // Do some logic with valA and valB
    }
  
    // ... rest of your component code
}
```

Also if this component is rendering something that relies on the result of the registerUpdate() function, you can consider adding conditional rendering. may be just render a loading state.

Comment: This is not a timing issue. Even after the mounting of the component, the store properties can be updated some 5 minutes later based on the data populated by the user.

Comment: Another thing that I noticed is that this is more or less linked to creating a closure based on the registration. When I access the closure from dev tools as and when my handleUpdate() is called, since it comes from another service file, I m seeing older values only.